# Is the System.Web.Silverlight reference needed?

Tags: silverlight

We are just getting into Silverlight development at my workplace. Somehow two of our dev machines have been configured differently. I noticed that one of them has access to System.Web.Silverlight in the reference list, and the other doesn't. Both can create and run Silverlight applications from scratch.

What does System.Web.Silverlight do? Is it a legacy reference? If we need it, where do we get it from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This dll provided the ASP.NET Silverlight server control which was designed to make it easier to create the object tag needed to describe the silverlight plug-in.

This server-side control was removed as of Silverlight 3, you are now expected to build the object tag yourself.

So yes its legacy so you don't need it.

Comment: +1 thanks for teaching me something new.  I always used the object tag anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Anthony is correct. If you are having trouble after you upgrade your products to Silverlight 3 - or just want an example on how to insert your SL app in to a page, create a new SL3 project and check out the sample ASPX and HTML pages (which are pretty much the same as each other now...)